# Logic tree with tikz-tree -- placing nodes on specific places

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I am trying to reproduce the following with tikz:

[image]

And also:

[image]

Regarding the first image I could start with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\begin{displaymath}
((\neg Qb \wedge x (Px \rightarrow Qx)) 
\tikz[baseline]\node (n1)     {$\rightarrow$}; \neg Pb)
\end{displaymath}


\begin{displaymath}
(\neg Qb \wedge \tikz[baseline]\node (n2) {$\forall$};x 
(Px \rightarrow Qx)) \qquad \tikz[baseline]\node (n3) {$\neg Pb$};
\end{displaymath}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]

\draw (n1) -- (n2); 
\draw (n1) -- (n3); 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result, however, is far from elegant, and I do not know how to proceed from that:

[image]

Comment: Does it have to use tikz? I can do the first if I don't have to use tikz! (Not sure about the second as I've not tried but I've typeset a bunch of the first kind.)

Comment: By the way, why are you trying to typeset logical errors? Is this for some sort of spot-the-error exercise? (I only ask because I'm curious having just typeset one - it is much harder to typeset it wrong than right! I don't mean the typesetting is harder - just I kept finding myself doing a bit correctly instead of copying the picture.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first tree, if the branches do not need to start from the main logical connectives, then the TikZ-based `forest` package would be a good option.

The second tree can also be drawn using `forest`, as if it were growing from bottom to top.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\renewcommand\b[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={parent anchor=south,child anchor=north}
  [$((\lnot Qb \wedge \forall x(Px \to Qx)) \to \lnot Pb)$, s=1cm
    [$(\lnot Qb \wedge \forall x (Px\to Qx))$
      [$\lnot Qb$
        [$Qb$]
      ]
      [$\forall x (Px\to Qx)$
        [$(Px\to Qx)$
          [$Px$]
          [$Qx$]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [$\lnot Pb$
      [$Pb$]
    ]
  ]
  \node[below,red]at(current bounding box.south){Figure: First Tree};
\end{forest}
%
\hskip20pt
%  
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    child anchor=south,grow'=north,
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor)-|(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
  },
  [\b{V}
    [\b{F}
      [\b{V}[$(C$,no edge]]
      [$\wedge$,no edge,tier=final]
      [\b{F}[$B)$,no edge]]
    ]
    [\b{V},name=n
      [$\to$,no edge,tier=final]
      [,no edge,name=nc
        [$\lnot$,no edge,tier=final]
      ]
      [\b{F}[$D$,no edge,tier=final]]
    ]
  ]
  \draw(n.north)--(nc.north);
  \node[below,red]at(current bounding box.south){Figure: Second Tree};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Ouch - the thing about centring on main connectives hadn't occurred to me though I can see why you might want to do that. I wonder if there is any neat way of achieving that. Can forest cope with the second example? I've only ever used qtree and have no idea how to typeset a 'tree' of that sort.

Comment: @cfr: I can't think of any neat way of making the tree branching off from the main connectives... I tried manually drawing it, but it's too messy. I'm working on the second example now. The way I'm approaching it is to draw a tree that "grows" from bottom to top.

Comment: I think the xyling package might possibly be able to do it but it looks to be extremely complicated to adapt for symbolic logic. (It's default assumption is all node labels will be short as in linguists' trees.) I think it would require so much manual adjustment that it would either be a real mess or an (under-appreciated) work of art!

Comment: Forest looks really fantastic - too bad it wasn't around the year before when I was looking into this stuff. (Though qtree worked out pretty well for my needs.)

Comment: @cfr: Yeah, `forest` is a really great. I like it for its slightly simpler syntax than the other alternatives, and that it's TikZ-based. But it takes a bit of learning, even if one is already sufficiently familiar with TikZ. I still have a long way to go before mastering this package.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is any use as it does not use tikz but here is how I would typeset the first example using the qtree package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\Tree
  [.{$((\neg Qb \wedge \forall x (Px \rightarrow Qx)) \rightarrow \neg Pb)$}
    [.{$(\neg Qb \wedge \forall x (Px \rightarrow Qx))$}
      [.{$\neg Qb$}
        [.{$Qb$}
        ]
      ]
      [.{$\forall x (Px \rightarrow Qx)$}
        [.{$(Px \rightarrow Qx)$}
          [.{$Px$}
          ]
          [.{$Qx$}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [.{$\neg Pb$}
      [.{$Pb$}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{document}
```

[image: beautiful typesetting courtesy of qtree; horrible logic courtesy of the question!]

**Warning: This is NOT correct logically but is, in fact, full of errors. Do not use this if you are learning logic just because it happens to be on a website!**

Note that older versions of qtree apparently had issues with pdflatex but the current version is compatible (and I've always used it with pdflatex).

Comment: It was just someone who happens to teach logic who asked for help to typeset this as a presenation to his students. I had no idea it was wrong. Do the connectives have to be as in the example, or can they appear as in your answer above?

Comment: My use of qtree was originally based on recommended packages from the LaTeX for Logicians website and I used this to teach logic seminars. Logically, it doesn't matter at all. Pedagogically, branching from the main connective would be nice but I haven't seen any solution which permits that. Plus I think that any such solution is going to make it really hard to create balanced trees of any kind as sometimes it will just make things ridiculously lopsided. One alternative would be to highlight the main connective which I think would be equally effective for teaching but much easier to implement.

Comment: I am really not sure if this is the place, but could you please tell me what errors you found in the tree? Or would that be a question for `http://math.stackexchange.com/`?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an SE site for philosophy though I guess it is maths, too. Anyway, at the first branch, the left hand side should be negated. So everything else in the left main branch is also wrong. Also, there is nothing which would justify entering Pb in the terminal of the right hand branch. On the left, x occurs as an unbound variable which is almost certainly not permitted and, even if it were, Px would need to be negated. And there is nothing which would justify entering Qb even if everything above it was correct.

Comment: The and elimination is the only case where the rules are applied correctly. (Obviously since the preceding line is wrong, this is also wrong but if the preceding line were correct, the application of and elimination would be correct.) That is, unless this is some very, very funky logic which is extremely non-standard. I'm assuming this is basically first-order propositional calculus and that the connectives have their standard meanings, that the system is sound etc.

Comment: Great, I have posted a question in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630629/what-is-wrong-with-this-logic-tree/630639, if you want to take a look.

Comment: @Joseph I cannot comment or answer there as I cannot login there. I get errors from SE when I try to login with my SE identity. However, the answer which Shaun gave you there is basically what I said above. What textbook did you find this in?!

Comment: It was from "Introdução à Lógica" (Introduction to Logic), by Cezar Mortari. (http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%C3%A0_l%C3%B3gica.html?id=6iS4_QGZzHAC&redir_esc=y). I had never heard of it before someone posted a question about reproducing that with TikZ.

Comment: @Joseph This is really off topic here. I wouldn't understand that book's text even if I had a copy but I'm assuming it is some sort of 'find the errors' exercise. It is certainly not valid in any standard system of propositional calculus (or any other I can think of - I'm no expert but a system which just asserts the opposite of statements for no reason doesn't seem likely to hold much interest!).

Comment: @Joseph, cfr : Couldn't this just be an illustration of the predicates on which the truth value of the main proposition turns? If that's what this is, then this is 'correct'. This would be my guess, otherwise it really would make *no sense* to go from `~Pb` to `Pb`, as cfr has pointed out. *I.e*, this could be a tree-like take of a truth table for the proposition.

Comment: Also, there is a philosophy site in beta: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Joseph: I can't edit comments but I don't know why I wrote 'propositional' rather than 'predicate' calculus. It should be the latter, of course. (Since it contains predicates and everything.)

Comment: @Adam (Px -> Qx), Px and Qx are not well-formed formulae at all in most languages. There is no sense in which the truth of (\forall x) (Px -> Qx) depends on the truth of Px or Qx or (Px -> Qx) since none of those *can* be true or false. In most languages (certainly most you'd see in introductory texts), well-formed formulae require all variables to be *bound* i.e. within the scope of a quantifier. You can't construct truth tables for predicate calculus. You can only do something analogous given a finite domain. Then you have to enumerate over all possible values of each variable e.g. x.

Comment: Right, which is why I thought it might be an illustration of just the predicates (not the sentences) on which the truth value of the proposition turns. Ultimately, (\forall x) (Px -> Qx) still depends on what Px and Qx mean (or, more accurately, on what P and Q mean), but not the truth-value of Px and Qx. So I suppose the 'tree-like take of a truth table' comment wasn't an accurate representaiton of what I actually meant. At any rate, I'm just trying to rationalize this drawing. I agree that it largely makes no sense. `:-)`

Comment: @Adam I see. Yes, that would make some sense. I thought maybe it was intended to demonstrate common errors because the errors are ones you see a lot in exercises completed by students tackling formal logic for the first time. If your system doesn't rely on trees for proofs, though, I guess you might use something like this as you suggest. As you say, it largely makes no sense and I suspect trying to guess its purpose is a somewhat futile exercise. Unless somebody has a copy of the book and the requisite language skills, we'll probably never know!